# Find out the version of Go a Binary was built with?

Tags: go

Is there a way to tell what go version a binary was built with?

I have multiple go instances on my workstation, so I want to verify that the correct one was used.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [runtime.Version()](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Version) at runtime to figure out what version of Go your binary was built with:

> ```
> func Version() string
> ```
>
> Version returns the Go tree's version string. It is either a sequence
> number or, when possible, a release tag like "release.2010-03-04". A
> trailing + indicates that the tree had local modifications at the time
> of the build.

For existing binaries, use the `go version` command:

> usage: `go version [-m] [-v] [file ...]`
>
> Version prints the build information for Go executables.
>
> Go version reports the Go version used to build each of the named
> executable files.
>
> If no files are named on the command line, go version prints its own
> version information.
>
> If a directory is named, go version walks that directory, recursively,
> looking for recognized Go binaries and reporting their versions.
> By default, go version does not report unrecognized files found
> during a directory scan. The `-v` flag causes it to report unrecognized files.
>
> The `-m` flag causes go version to print each executable's embedded
> module version information, when available. In the output, the module
> information consists of multiple lines following the version line, each
> indented by a leading tab character.

Comment: Can you provide an usage examples? (for those that don't know go at all) Do you need to change the application binary?

Answer (score 47):

The following command should do it:

```
# strings binary_path | grep 'go1\.' 
go1.5.3
```

Comment: Indeed, good solution when you need to know the version without rebuilding the binary

Comment: this is good, my grep result returns more than one result. The last one is the correct one in my case

Comment: I would recommend doing `grep '^go1\.'` instead to filter out other string literals

Answer (score 18):

Use `go version <path>`.

```sh
$ go version /usr/bin/syncthing
/usr/bin/syncthing: go1.13.10

$ go version
go version go1.14.3 linux/amd64
```