# How to determine which Go version was used to compile a binary

Tags: go

When I run the command

```
go build
```

I end up with an application that's larger than needed, doesn't run and with lots of errors. I'm using the same source as everybody else and I understand the different OS make a difference, but should it affect the actual program and how it works?

How do I find out what version of Go was used and which compiler was used on a already-compiled application? It's just a app file.

Comment: first check environment variables using `go env` to check the `gopath` and `goroot`

Comment: More details on the errors you are getting may help answering this question

Comment: Best advice is: Ask the person who is teaching you.

Comment: Regarding "too large", that [was already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49492026/720999). Regarding errors, we need to see *what exact errors.*

Comment: Add the output from the `go version` and `go env` commands` to your question.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be deleted instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: Mor important than the compiler version should be the OS. Looks like an XY problem and a communication problem. You should talk to your tutor, if you can't get a different tutor.

Comment: Because this question appears in search results, I need to redirect it to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990242/find-out-the-version-of-go-a-binary-was-built-with

Comment: go version ./myprogram  (for programs compiled with a recente version of go)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing `go build` you are creating a binary for the go program in that current folder.

### Update

<s>Once a binary file is created you **cannot determine** what version      of `Go` was used to create the binary.</s>

To Find the version of `GO` used for compiling use a debugger like `gdb` or others. Here is an awesome [blog](https://dave.cheney.net/2017/06/20/how-to-find-out-which-go-version-built-your-binary) about the same.

And you can inspect the file with

```
file mybinary
```

to get info like the type of binary and like which OS it is supposed to run on.

eg : `ELF` files run on `Linux`
     `Mach-O` files run on `Mac` etc...

However you can `cross compile` your Go code with

```
GOOS=linux go build
```

so this creates a binary for `linux (ELF file)` even though i run Go on `Mac` / `Windows`

Comment: you're a genius. Thank you so much for taking the time to reply. This was what i was looking for. <3

Comment: Actually the Go version used to compile the binary is recorded in the binary.

Comment: Any idea on how to get that info @icza ?

Comment: @ShivaKishore [Dave Cheney: How to find out which Go version built your binary](https://dave.cheney.net/2017/06/20/how-to-find-out-which-go-version-built-your-binary)